# MySQL export tables with prefix from Unix command line

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, export, mediawiki

I want to export certain tables from one database and import them to another. The tables in question are used for my MediaWiki installation and are prefixed with "wiki_".

I do not have access to phpMyAdmin, but I am able to connect to the server via SSH. I'm guessing I need to use the `mysqldump` command, but how do I specify that I only want to dump tables prefixed with "wiki_"?

Comment: There's a manual page for this. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to generate the list of tables you want to dump then act upon it.

```
mysql -u USER -p -D test -Bse "show tables like 'wiki_%'" >tables.out
mysqldump -u USER -p test <tables.out >wiki_tables.dump
```

or as a one liner

```
mysqldump -u USER -p test $(mysql -u USER -p -D test -Bse "show tables like 'wiki_%'")
```

but you still get to enter the password twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since `mysqldump` can't work with wildcards, you will have to specify the tables you want:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database wiki_table1 wiki_table2 .. > database.sql
```

Or you could specify the tables you don't want to export:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=atable --ignore-table=anothertabl > database.sql
```